# Replacing multiple div content with other content and being able to cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have the following:

```
<div class="ArrowLeft"></div>
<div class="ArrowRight"></div>
<div class="ReviewComment">
<p>“Thank you for making selling our car so painless.”</p>
</div>
<div class="ReviewName">
</div>
</div>
```

I've been looking at different ways to get it to work so that when click one of the "Arrow" buttons, it replaces the content in "ReviewComment". However so far i've only managed to get it to replace the content going one way. So for example when it gets to the 5th div's content, it won't then click back to the first one?

I've tried multiple different ways of doing this but I can't seem to get it to cycle through as I would like.

I also can't seem to get it to replace the content of ReviewName at the same time as ReviewComment.

Comment: add the your code in jsfiddle and share it

Comment: @VairaMuthu at the moment I have this https://jsfiddle.net/knjz1v8f/ as I'm also trying to make it scroll through. I will try and get some of the old stuff I did, although I don't feel it was very good!

Comment: @VairaMuthu I know have the following which is cycling and reacting to the button clicks, but is there a way to make it change both divs?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of what comment you're on, and how many comments there are. If total comments == current comment, go back to the first one. Ex code:

```
var comments = ['comment 1', 'comment 2', 'comment 3', 'comment 4', 'comment 5'];
var currentComment = 0;
var totalComments = comments.length - 1;

$('.arrowRight').click(function(){
    currentComment++;

  if(currentComment > totalComments){
    // past last comment, load first
    $('.comments .comment').html(comments[0]);
    currentComment = 0;
  }else{
    $('.comments .comment').html(comments[currentComment]);
  }

    console.log(currentComment);
})

$('.arrowLeft').click(function(){
    currentComment--;

  if(currentComment < 0){
    // past first comment, load last
    $('.comments .comment').html(comments[totalComments]);
    currentComment = totalComments;
  }else{
    $('.comments .comment').html(comments[currentComment]);
  }

  console.log(currentComment);
})
```

T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ I don't know how you're fetching your comments. But you can transplant the logic from the example in to your own code. Hopefully this gets you on your way.

I'll try and edit with a js fiddle shortly.

## UPDATE

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mpr9j6sd/

Comment: Thanks for this bud, however I need to replace 2 divs contents relating to each other. I would also prefer the div's to replace in full so that I can style div's differently if required. I've got the following doing nearly what I want to do https://jsfiddle.net/knjz1v8f/1/ however I just can't get it to replace multiple divs. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you're attempting here. What divs are you trying to replace and what are you trying to replace them with? Where is your content coming from? From what I can tell, you're trying to replace the review and the reviewers name. Are you trying to replace the surrounding div too?

Comment: The reviews will be coming from a MySQL database, and i'd like to echo out the results in to the divs, so that I have 5 review comment divs `<div class="ReviewComment-x">`, 5 reviewer name divs `<div class="ReviewBy-x">` and then for these to scroll through (this wasn't a plan initially, but I've since made it work and I like the idea) and also be manually over-ridden. I've kind of got the scroll through working for one of the divs, but struggling to get it working for both at the same time and on click working properly.

Comment: Have you considered this approach? Updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mpr9j6sd/1/

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible, and this will sound very strange but it's part of the design, and it's not possible for them to be in the same container.

Comment: You could take it out of the container. Change the part of the javascript that targets the container and add two lines instead; Change container:eq for comment:eq and review:eq etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101888/discussion-between-lewis-and-bn83).